# Stop program when thread finished

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I'm a newbie in C#. I have a windows service. In this service, I run a thread. I want to stop the service immediately after the thread finish. Currently, my code is like:

```
while(true){
     if(isThreadFinished){
          MyService.Stop();
          break;
     }
}
```

It work, but I feel that using while(true) like that is a stupid way. So, I want to know if there is any other way to achieve my request.

Comment: What makes you feel it's a stupid way?

Comment: @Shane.C because CPU usage will skyrocket for no good reason this way.

Comment: Its not a stupid way per say but it will involve a lot of processing, you may wish to use a timer instead and only check if the thread is finished after X ammount of milliseconds

Comment: @Shane.C When i debugging, I see that the program have to run both thread and while(true)... at the same time, so, if the thread have to run in a long time, i'm afraid that it will slow down my program.

Comment: Why you can´t ust call MyService.Stop as a last step in the execution thread?

Comment: Of course it's st.. inappropriate.  One core and memory-bandwidth down the drain.

Comment: What happens if you call 'ExitProcess(0)' as the last line of the thread code?

Comment: @ne2dmar;Martin James: Oh sh.t, sometime I feel so stupid, thanks u!

Comment: @user2500561 - sometimes the simplest ways are the best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And Why don't use the delegate? 
You have a sample and the documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/900fyy8e%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) , in the official MSDN website...

You just call you're delegate method before the end of your Thread...

That's more proprely that a while loop... and more optimize if your thread during a long time...

Answer (score 1):

```
bool x=true;
while(x==true){
 if(isThreadFinished){
      x=false;
      MyService.Stop();
      break;
 }
}
```

Comment: break will exit the loop, the rest of the padding is irrelevant

Answer (score 0):

I don't know C#, but usually you would have an API thread.join() or similar which waits for the thread to finish.

If nothing else you can block on the same synchronised object.

In Java, there's also Object.wait() and Object.notify() that does the trick.